# Python subprocess hangs when using stdout=subprocess.PIPE

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following simple command in Python which returns a directory associated with the `Node.js`

```
import subprocess
import shutil
cmd = [shutil.which("npm"), 'bin']
subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I've tested this on two different systems, on my Mac it runs almost instantly whereas on my Windows 10 system it hangs for a long time even though running the command `npm bin` in the terminal completes immediately. Running other commands, say `cmd = [shutil.which("condo"), "info"]` works fine. If I don't specify the `stdout` argument it will also work OK. I would like to figure why it is hanging and how to fix that.

**UPDATE**

Also tried

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

On Windows 10 under Python 3.6.10, same result as running `subprocess.run()`.

Comment: How big is the "npm bin" output? PIPE is a memory buffer and if the buffer is full there is a chance the process will hang and the limit can be different between OSes. Can you try with a command with controlled output length like echo "smth"?

Comment: Small about, less than 50 characters

Comment: You need to actually consume the output. If `which` is sitting around waiting to be able to write (because the other side of the FIFO has no reader), that does you no good.

Comment: Easiest way to get a reader is to use `communicate()` explicitly. Some newer versions of Python 3 have a way to have `run()` do an explicit read, but you haven't said which version you're using,  and IIRC it may require an explicit option.

Comment: Edited the original post, I was not able to use `communicate()` although I'm not sure if I'm running it correctly. Tried with the `shell` argument as both True and False for `Popen()`